# TraceListener handle errors between totally unrelated components

Tags: c#, .net, logging, owin, system.data.sqlite

I added the new (NuGet) component *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost* to an existing and working multihreaded application which makes heavy use of *System.Data.SQLite* using *EntityFramework*.

Now totally unpredictible any query randomly can fail with a callstack which shows that the added *Owin* component somehow integrated into the internal logging system of .NET (which I personally neither understand nor do use (I use *NLog* instead)) using a `Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Tracing.DualWriter`:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException occurred
  HResult=-2146232004
  Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)
       at MyQueryExecution.SomeCode()
  InnerException: System.IO.IOException
       HResult=-2147024890
       Message=The handle is invalid.

       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
            at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
            at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Tracing.DualWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
            at System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.WriteLine(String message)
            at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message)
            at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.LogCallback(IntPtr pUserData, Int32 errorCode, IntPtr pMessage)
            at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_prepare_interop(IntPtr db, IntPtr pSql, Int32 nBytes, IntPtr& stmt, IntPtr& ptrRemain, Int32& nRemain)
            at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
            at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
            at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
            at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
            at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
            at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
       InnerException:
```

I already tried disabling logging on SQLite side:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Enabled = false;
```

and on Owin:

```
appBuilder.Properties.Remove("host.TraceOutput");
appBuilder.Properties.Remove("host.TraceSource");
appBuilder.Properties.Remove("server.LoggerFactory");
```

But with no success/change.

Comment: It looks like there is another inner exception (at the bottom) that you forgot to paste.

Comment: @zespri no, there is nothing below this line and nothing at the right side after the colon. I pasted everything which VisualStudio copied to clipboard using "copy exception details to clipboard".

Comment: can you check your web.config for owin trace listeners? they should be under <system.diagnostics> section and are probably added by the nuget package.

Comment: @zespri It's a console/service application so there only is an app.config. But there has nothing been added to <system.diagnostics>